# Get the deleted row's index in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I deleted a row in my DataGridView by selecting it and pressing *Delete* and would like to get the row's index. How could i do that?

Comment: Hi. its no duplicate. please help me...

Comment: Please post your code .. that you tried.. And Are you using ItemCommand or such type of event to delete???

Answer (score 4):

You may obtain an index before you delete a row by handling `UserDeletingRow` event.

```
 dataGridView1.UserDeletingRow += (sa, ea) =>
  {
    MessageBox.Show(ea.Row.Index.ToString())
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the selected index of the current selected item:

```
int index = DataGrid1.SelectedIndex;
```

You can do this before deleting the item and you will know the index.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the answers in StackOverflow mentioned `UserDeletedRow` as an event to handle and get the user deleted row index. this event only fired after deleting that row.
The correct one must be `UserDeletingRow`, where by this event you can do something before you lose the deleted row.
Now how to get the row index? the answer by using the below code

```
private void dataGridView1_UserDeletingRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        int tmp = e.Row.Index;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this will help you.

```
private void EvtBindingNavigatorDeleteItemClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   ToolStripButton MyToolStripButton = (ToolStripButton)sender;
   CustomBindingNavigator MyCustomBindingNavigator = 
   (CustomBindingNavigator)MyToolStripButton.GetCurrentParent();
   CustomDataGridView MyDataGridView = GetDataGridView(MyCustomBindingNavigator);
   int RowIndexDelete = -1;
   BindingSource MyBindingSource = MyCustomBindingNavigator.BindingSource;
   DataTable MyDataTable = (DataTable)MyBindingSource.DataSource;
   foreach ( DataRow MyDataRow in MyDataTable.Rows)
   {
    if (MyDataRow.RowState == DataRowState.Deleted)
        RowIndexDelete = MyDataTable.Rows.IndexOf(MyDataRow);
   }
}
```